# need help to get jinja2 to work

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am working on getting Jinja2 to work with Google AppEngine.  I have the following for my main.py code:

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True, 
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {
            'name': 'SomeGuy',
            'verb': 'extremely enjoy'
        }

    template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

This has been killing me for hours I would be grateful for some help.

UPDATE:

I have changed the code a bit to update the situation.  The logs are telling me:

```
ImportError: <module 'main' from '/base/data/home/apps/s~devpcg/1.359633215335673018/main.pyc'> has no attribute app
```

and the above code is all from my main.py folder.  I have a file index.html in a folder called templates that is in the same directory as the main.py file.

Comment: Looks good to me. Are you getting any errors? Have you tried deploying to GAE? If so, how does it look? Do you have jinja2 specified in your `app.yaml`? The `jinja_environment` line is just telling jinja where to find the templates directory relative to the path of the current file. So if you had that code in a `main.py` file, you'd want a `templates` directory at the same level as the `main.py` file.

Comment: Here is a very simple -- but confirmed to be working! -- application which may help you envision how things come together: https://bitbucket.org/abernier/anotherday/src But your code really seems fine as is.

Comment: it is just giving me a 500 Server Error when I deploy to GAE.  and I am not getting any other errors

Comment: Try looking at the logs to see what the actual error is. Those can be viewed using the admin tools.

Comment: it is telling me: IndentationError: unexpected indent
INFO     2012-06-15 04:33:02,917 dev_appserver.py:2904] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: I thought maybe this was simply a copy-paste error, but your `class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):` should be unindented one level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not sure if this is a copy-paste error when pasting your code over to stackoverflow, but you do seem to be getting an indentation error as indicated in the comments...
This is the correct indentation:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {
            'name': 'SomeGuy',
            'verb': 'extremely enjoy'
        }

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

---

Edit:
Based on the new error I would recommend you give a little bit more information about how your application is structured.
I am guessing that you are showing us your `main.py` file.
If that is indeed the case you need to have something like the code below in that file (assuming Python 2.7).
For more-granular details please refer to the documentation:
 https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27#Configure_WSGI_Script_Handlers

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes=[ 
    ( r'/', MainPage ),
    # ... other paths ...
], debug=True) # True for now until ready for prod...
```

Comment: I just updated the situation in the question.  Let me know if you need any further information.  Thanks!

Comment: Looking good. What you have is almost there. Simply add `app = ` before the last line in your `main.py` file: `webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)` such that it looks like: `app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)` Because that's what your `app.yaml` is (most likely) telling GAE to look for.

Comment: Don't sweat it. This kind of thing happens to everyone. Glad you got it working.